# Re-size the width and height of gridster's widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gridster

I am developing a dashboard using Gridster. Based on some documents, it seems that the unit of widget's dimensions is pixels. So is there a way to define the width and height of widget using the percentage relative to the parent container?

Thanks